# Data rendered to jquery datatable using innerHTML shows "No data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform, datatables

I'm new to javascript. I'm developing a web app using javascript and HTML. Here is the code:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive">
    <thead>
     <tr>
    <th>No:</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Date registered</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="result11" >
<script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("keyyyyyy", "idddddddddddddddddddddd");
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("doctor_details");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                var docname = object.get('doc_name');
                var date = object.get('doc_regdate');
                var k = i + 1;
                document.getElementById('result11').innerHTML +="<tr ><td>"+k+"</td><td>"+docname+"</td><td>"+date+"</td><td>doctor</td><td><a class='btn btn-info' href='edit-doctor.php'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white'></i>Edit</a></td></tr>";

            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });


  </script>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The problem is that I fetch data from parse using javascript parse sdk and render the data to the "tbody" of the data table using inner HTML. Here I get data table showing "no data".Dynamic data displaying only after the data table is displayed.[image: this is what I get.Data fetched is not served to the datatable.]

Pagination,search nothing is working.
I need to know how can I render data when the data table loads.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not using datatables correctly here, you've just populated the table using jquery. Please post the datatables initialisation code.

Comment: @markpsmith i just include the datatable library in the head tag .

Comment: I think you need to find a tutorial as it looks like you're a bit lost, eg [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: @markpsmith so you are saying that it is not possible to directly render dynamic data to HTML data table using inner HTML?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible - that's what you've done! I'm saying that you're not making use of the correct datatables initialisation procedure, which is why it's not working.

Comment: @markpsmith  Its working when document.getElementById('').innerHTML is put after the execution  of  query.find(), but data cannot be retrieved in that case.what to do?